# Creating a QT ROS package

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do i create a ros package that has QT GUI? Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274099/creating-a-qt-ros-package/) by [MechLc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29880/mechlc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use `catkin_create_qt_pkg`. But it will probably generate some project which is not compileable (or at least in was like it my case). It depends on version of your `ROS`, `qt` etc.

[Here](http://www.cnblogs.com/casperwin/p/6206193.html) is a great tutorial on how to do that. But in my case I had to modify it's `CMakeLists.txt` to be able to build it. I also had to rename `QtGui` include in `main_window.hpp`.

From this `#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>`
to this `#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>`.

I've added my example package [here](https://github.com/L4ncelot/qtros_example) on github so take look.

---

Originally posted by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) with karma: 826 on 2017-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MechLc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29880/mechlc/) on 2017-11-10**:
For some reason its not working for Kinetic

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-11-13**:
I've tried this on kinetic so it should work imo. Have you followed the guide to make sure your `qt` is installed properly?

**Comment by [Valveware](https://answers.ros.org/users/32824/valveware/) on 2018-01-10**:
Hey l4ncelot, when trying to open your github example I can run catkin_make succesfully but when opening it in Qt I get:CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "roscpp" ...
Can you help me?

**Comment by [MechLc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29880/mechlc/) on 2018-01-10**:
Hey Valveware,
I used this package I found :
https://github.com/stonier/qt_ros
add it to your workspace. If you have questions let me know.
Thanks!

**Comment by [Valveware](https://answers.ros.org/users/32824/valveware/) on 2018-01-10**:
Does that work for Kinetic? I now did the following steps:

1. followed the installguide
2. cloned l4's example and qt_rosinto my source folder
3. ran catkin_make on my workspace ( no errors)
4. Qt -> open project -> catkin_ws/src/qtros_example/ CMakeLists.txt with the standard kit

**Comment by [Valveware](https://answers.ros.org/users/32824/valveware/) on 2018-01-10**:
Now the last step gives an error in Qt: CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "roscpp". What am I still doing wrong? Qt Creator 4.5.0 based on Qt 5.10.0. Thanks in advance!

**Comment by [Valveware](https://answers.ros.org/users/32824/valveware/) on 2018-01-10**:
Is this perhaps a better solution for me? https://answers.ros.org/question/275578/ros-kinetic-gui-help/ I also which to create a GUI to interact with a Turtlebot running on ROS. EDIT: Solved it with this thread thanks!